# Copy pages at the push of a button without Javascript for Apple devices

Tags: pdf, acrobat

i want to use a button to copy an existing pdf page in the form itself. this works with javascript by spawning a page template. Unfortunately this does not work on apple devices.

Adobe Acrobat Pro DC

```
var a = this.getTemplate ("template");  
a.spawn();
```

Works on Windows and not for ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you are using Adobe Acrobat Reader on iOS (or Android) the JavaScript to spawn pages isn't supported. I don't see that it's supported in PDF Expert by Readdle either. That functionality is only supported on Windows and macOS.

For the list of supported JavaScript on iOS, see the link below. It's a quick read; the list is very short.
https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/index.html